# MudTable: colored blinking cell

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I have such a problem. I have a method that changes the color of a cell.

```
 private string GetCellStyle(DateTime odbior, DateTime realizacja)
 {
     if (odbior <= realizacja)
     {
        
         return "color:" + animation_color + "; font - size: 2.9rem; font - weight:500; text - align:center;";
     }
     else
     {
         return " font - size: 0.9rem; font - weight:500; text - align:center;";
     }

 }
```

Calling a method in a table:

```
 <MudTd  Style="@GetCellStyle(context.odbior, context.realizacja)" DataLabel="Wysyłka">@context.odbior.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</MudTd>
```

I need color animation to change the color to another one after 3 seconds.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Timer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-7.0).

With the timer you can set an intervall in which a Method to change `animation_color` is called.

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(3000);
    timer.Elapsed += Coloring;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Enabled = true;
```

With `Coloring`

```
private void Coloring(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e){
    animation_color = $"#{rnd.Next(999999)}";
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wYGnlPFUHgPtFxeb

Comment: Can you help that the icon in mudicon has changed instead of its color?

Comment: You can do this by Changeing the 'Icon' attribute. I'd say it's best to create a Icon list and iterate through it.
There's a snippet on mudblazor itself https://mudblazor.com/components/icons#custom-icons
And you would do it like that:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GkGHlvPUJGgbgeQq